# Slider Jquery - Galeria de fotos -PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera, estou procurando esse slider, mas não consigo encontrar, preciso deste tipo, as imagens vem do banco de dados e conforme eu arrasto a bolinha, as imagens mudam, alguém sabe onde posso encontrar?

Comment: É só um slider que tem uma barrinha pra passar as imagens? Ou cada "passada" vão ter 4 imagens que dá pra dar zoom em cada uma individualmente?

Comment: @Guerra cada passada vai ter 4 imagens, mas nao eh zoom eu to utilizando colorbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exatamente do jeito que você quer tipo pegar e já sair usando não conheço nenhum.

Provavelmente você vai ter que pegar um mais ou menos parecido e customizar.

Sugiro alguns.

[JSSor](http://www.jssor.com) < esse é muito bom e opensource.

[Grid Slider](http://onether.com/grid-slider/) legal mas pago $6

Mais alguns exemplos [aqui](http://jquery-plugins.net/category/grid-layout)

Espero ter ajudado.